# Algebraic solution of Dirac equation for Coulomb potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, dirac-equation, hydrogen, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

The Runge-Lenz operator enables an algebraic solution of Coulomb potential energy levels without a solution of a differential equation.  What is the analog for the solution of the Dirac equation in a Coulomb potential and the associated energy levels.  Is it possible to get the energy levels solely by algebraic methods and not solving the coupled differential equations.  I have seen separation into angular and radial parts by algebraic means, but the radial equation always seems to be solved via the usual power series methods.  Can this be avoided by using an analog of the Runge-Lenz operator for the Dirac equation?

Comment: From akhmeteli: 

L I Komarov and T S Romanova 1985 J. Phys. B: At. Mol. Phys. 18 859 The algebraic method of solution of the Dirac equation for a particle in a Coulomb potential.   

Abstract:An equation is constructed in two-dimensional complex space, in the set of solutions of which solutions of the Dirac equation for a particle in a Coulomb potential are present. These solutions are found by a purely algebraic method.   

I have not seen the article though.

Answer (score 1):

L I Komarov and T S Romanova 1985 J. Phys. B: At. Mol. Phys. 18 859
The algebraic method of solution of the Dirac equation for a particle in a Coulomb potential

Abstract:An equation is constructed in two-dimensional complex space, in the set of solutions of which solutions of the Dirac equation for a particle in a Coulomb potential are present. These solutions are found by a purely algebraic method.

I have not seen the article though.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/221925)

Comment: @sammygerbil : I don't quite get it: there is no link in my answer, just a reference to a paper article. How can it change? And I provided the abstract.

Comment: Sorry the text of the comment was generated automatically without me seeing it. I flagged the answer as "link only" because it directs the user to an answer without explaining what that answer is.

Comment: @sammygerbil : "answer without explaining what that answer is" - I would think the abstract does explain "what the answer is", that it is "possible to get the energy levels solely by algebraic methods and not solving the coupled differential equations"

Comment: In short, your answer is "Yes, read this article". You could have provided some details of the method, whether it uses an analog of the Runge-Lenz operator, explained how the two problems differ.

Comment: @sammygerbil: An answer does not have to be complete.

Comment: No, but they should provide some context for the link and be more informative than just saying Yes or No with a link or reference. This answer only repeats the question and says "Yes, the answer is in this article." The issue isn't that the link could be broken, but that the details are "in another castle".  See Meta questions :  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110165/should-i-flag-answers-consisting-only-of-no-or-yes  and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: @sammygerbil : And according to the official rules, " Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful" (https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), so if my answer is not up to your high standards it is still up to the standards of the site.

Comment: Link-only answers also "get the asker going in the right direction", so there is some conflict here. As the script says, "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference." I did not write the script. This is the site's standard not mine.

Comment: @sammygerbil : And my answer is not link-only. So it seems you are trying to impose your own standards, not the site's ones.

Comment: Well, when voting everyone is following their own take on the site's rules, not trying to impose it. That said, I think this might provide a valuable pointer. Ideally it should be complemented with some information (I'd do it, but it's too outside my expertise for me to be able to do it easily enough). So that it's not lost (in case of deletion) I copied the content to a comment to the question.